# How to prevent user save loop in CP?

Tags: users

I have a plugin that uses its init function to save custom user data from front end registrations. It uses:

```
 if ($event->params['isNewUser']) {}
```

and

```
if (craft()->request->isSiteRequest()) {}
```

To perform front end save routines.

I want to add a small  custom user save rule for admin usage outside of the IsNewUser logic in order to preserve like this:

```
 if (craft()->request->isCpRequest()) {
   $user = craft()->users->getUserById($uidfromURL);
   $user->getContent()->URN = 'my custom value';
   $success = craft()->users->saveUser($user);
 }
```

The problem is that this code just loops thru the plugin. I need the custom field to be manually editable, but i also need to create a default value too on initial user creation in admin.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem a while ago when a plugin listened for `onSaveUser` and then saved the user itself, causing an infinite loop. Someone provided me something like:

```
craft()->on('users.onSaveUser', function(Event $event) {
    static $recursionLevel = 0;
    if ($recursionLevel == 0) {
        $recursionLevel++;
        // do your stuff
    }
});
```